# ¿Cómo obtener columna de una matriz?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero simplificar esta linea de código:

```
x = [c[0] for c in inputs]
```

Pregunto si hay un método sin usar `for`, intente `inputs[:][0]`, peor solo da el primer elemento.

Matriz de ejemplo:

```
inputs= [ (-2, 1/9),
          (-1, 1/3),
          (0, 1),
          (1, 3),
          (2, 9) ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo otra forma de resolver tu pregunta que no sea usando [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), esta librería esta especialmente dedicada (y optimizada) al manejo de objetos n-dimensionales, ideal para trabajar con matrices de todo tipo:

```
import numpy as np

inputs = [ (-2, 1/9),
          (-1, 1/3),
          (0, 1),
          (1, 3),
          (2, 9) ]

inputs = np.array(inputs)
print(inputs[:,0])
```

La salida:

```
[-2. -1.  0.  1.  2.]
```

Lo que estas haciendo es un slice de filas que contempla todas y tomando únicamente la columna correspondiente al índice 0. Si quisieras retornar una matriz como la original pero con una sola columnas:

Para más info ver [este](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) enlace.

```
print(inputs[:,0:1])
[[-2.]
 [-1.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 2.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer una *inversión* de la matriz con un *unzip*, que idiomáticamente sería algo así:

```
inputs_inv = list(zip(*inputs))
```

Para obtener la primera columna:

```
print(inputs_inv[0])
```

Lo que no tengo claro es si este modo de hacer las cosas es más simple que usar una compresión de listas.

Tampoco resulta eficiente, ya que se ha creado una nueva lista para almacenar la matriz invertida, siendo que sólo queríamos una columna. Se puede hacer mucho más eficiente usando únicamente iteradores, pero se complica la cosa. En general, lo recomendable sería usar *expresiones generadoras*.